# Splitting InputStream into multiple parts

Tags: java, io

I have InputStream (does not support marking) pointing to a large file. I want to split this InputStream to multiple input streams and be able to read them parallelly. I don't want to drain the entire stream in order to split in into parts. My idea is  to get something like the following :

```
    List<ChunkedInputSteam> streams = 
      ???Util???.getChunkedStreams(sourceInputStream, chunkSize)
```

At one moment the threads will execute the following:

```
    OutputStream out = new CountingOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    InputStream is = ??streams.get()
    ByteStreams.copy(is, out);
```

Until that moment I don't want to read data into the memory.
Is this possible to be achieved?

Comment: `InputStream` is an abstract class.  Do we know what class the `InputStream` actually is?

Comment: IO doesn't parallelize well. If you want to increase performance, you could try memory mapping the file. If that doesn't help, you're better off using your time on other things.

Comment: Implementation of InputStream adds some hooks to default implementation of InputStream - nothing special

Comment: Is there a reason you need to be using streams, or can you use anything that can access the file?

Comment: I am developing module which is tiеd up to container environment and this
 InputStream is what I have access to. Actually right now there is implementation which reads from this InputStream into multiple ByteArrayInputStream's but if source is too large this leads to OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Maybe you're better off showing us that code so we can suggest improvements?  But like Kayaman said, I don't think reading a file in parallel really does much for you; generally the IO itself is the bottleneck there.

Comment: Here is the the implementation with bytearrayinputstream : 
https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/io/internal/BasePayloadSlicer.java
It is from Apache Jclouds